# LibGDX http request not working

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to send a String message to database when user presses a specific button in the LibGDX game I am designing for android. How do I go about doing that? Following is the code I tried. But it does not work.

```
 Net.HttpRequest httpRequest = new Net.HttpRequest();
    httpRequest.setMethod("POST");
    httpRequest.setUrl("URL is here");
    httpRequest.setContent("INSERT INTO `game_table` (`Button`) VALUES ('Button 1 Pressed')");

    Net.HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener = new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            Gdx.app.log("Log httpResponse", httpResponse.getResultAsString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {

        }
    };
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest,httpResponseListener);
```

Log does not provide anything in android monitor. I also tried using AsyncTask and without AsyncTask to implement this code. But neither works.
Am I missing something? If so could you give me small code snippet that will work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an AsyncTask, libGDX' HTTPRequest is async out of the box.

You did not log anything if the request fails or is cancelled so probably that's the case.